# Nmap scan what does STATE=filtered mean?

Tags: nmap

When I scanned a host for open ports I came across the following result:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   open     http
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
3306/tcp open     mysql
```

What does filtered mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Filtered* is described in the [NMAP Reference Guide, Chapter 15](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html):

> Nmap cannot determine whether the port is open because packet
>   filtering prevents its probes from reaching the port. The filtering
>   could be from a dedicated firewall device, router rules, or host-based
>   firewall software. These ports frustrate attackers because they
>   provide so little information. Sometimes they respond with ICMP error
>   messages such as type 3 code 13 (destination unreachable:
>   communication administratively prohibited), but filters that simply
>   drop probes without responding are far more common. This forces Nmap
>   to retry several times just in case the probe was dropped due to
>   network congestion rather than filtering. This slows down the scan
>   dramatically.

Long story short - *Filtered* means you cannot access the port from your scanning location, but this doesn't mean the port is closed on the system itself. *Closed* on the other hand would mean, you can reach the port, but it is actually closed.

Comment: a closed port could also indicate a firewall blocking connections. compare basic firehol and ufw rules and corresponding nmap scans ;)

Answer (score 6):

Filtered is also a common response when scanning for **UDP**.

Scanning for UDP presents a number of challenges and the [nmap documentation](https://nmap.org/book/scan-methods-udp-scan.html) has a detailed discussion on **UDP** and the **filtered** status.

*Reminder: by default, nmap scans only for TCP against the 1000 most 'popular' ports.*

In the past I have used [Unicornscan](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Unicornscan) for this specific purpose because nmap has limitations, but there may be other tools that will perform adequately.
I would suggest that you try again with a UDP scan and see what you get. Perhaps add some flags like `-sV` to get nmap to dig further.

Ports 139 and 445 normally use tcp while ports 137, 138 use udp.

```
# iptables -A INPUT -d 10.1.1.1 -p udp --dport 137 -j DROP
# iptables -A INPUT -d 10.1.1.1 -p udp --dport 138 -j DROP
# iptables -A INPUT -d 10.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 139 -j DROP
# iptables -A INPUT -d 10.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 445 -j DROP
```

Source: [Firewalling Samba](https://www.samba.org/~tpot/articles/firewall.html)